# Cant insert a string in android resource file without getting an error

Tags: android, eclipse

How an I suppress this error:

```
<resources>
<string name='app_name'>PhoneMates</string>
<string name='app_url'>phonemates</string>
<string name='dom_url'>http://example.com/services/directlinkhandler.ashx?wid=124962546435&LinkID=1133&queryid=138&cid=8&promocode=GTJRPM</string>
<string name='loading'>Loading...</string>
```

It points me to the dom_url link and tells me that there has been an error.
The reference to LinkID must end with ';' delimiter.

How can I prevent/suppress that error, while maintaining the link?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try replacing your `&` (ampersands) with `&amp;`.

I have confirmed that this works in my environment.  The reason is that it will think everything past the ampersand is an [ampersand character code](http://rabbit.eng.miami.edu/info/htmlchars.html).

Comment: Also on that note, you should follow Lint, and replace your `...` with ellipsis (Replace "..." with ellipsis character (…, &&;#8230;) ?)

Comment: Also, you can accept the answer so others know this is the solution. ;)